# Need to comment out isapi filters in site.config after each IIS restart

Tags: iis, asp.net, .net

We are experiencing a weird issue that I cannot figure out and hope someone may be able to help me out.

When we restart one of our web servers, I have to go into the `site.config` to comment out a couple of references to `.net` in order to get our Wordpress site to start correctly.

For Windows, every time a server or IIS service is restarted, I have to update `Site.config` on `c:\inetpub\temp\appPools\Site\Site.config`.

```
<isapiFilters>
    <filter name="ASP.Net_2.0_for_V1.1" path="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll" preCondition="bitness32" />
    <filter name="ASP.Net_4.0_32bit" path="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll" preCondition="bitness32" />
    <filter name="ASP.Net_4.0_64bit" path="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll" preCondition="bitness64" /> 
</isapiFilters>
```

**I end up needing to put comment marks around the block to get the site to work correctly.**

Comment: Here's the error from the site when I move it into a new app pool:  Module IIS Web Core
Notification Unknown
Handler StaticFile
Error Code 0x800700b7
Config Error Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'filter' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'ASP.Net_2.0_for_V1.1'
Config File \\?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\apppoolname\apppoolname.config

Comment: Can you make that configuration through IIS Mgmt Console